# How to send flot chart using html email

Tags: c#, asp.net, flot

I need to send an e-mail in C# with html formatting. In the e-mail message, I'd like to include a flot.js chart and I don't know how. Can anyone suggest how I might include this chart in my mail?

Comment: Including JavaScript code in an email message probably won't work.  I imagine every mail client on the planet blocks JavaScript at this point.

Comment: You should render the chart as an image and include it in the email HTML or as an attachment.

Comment: Your email could contain an URL to a web page that includes the flot.js and does the drawing.

Comment: Ok, I'm finding this Rendering [HTML+Javascript server-side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391133/rendering-htmljavascript-server-side) but free.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer using the asp.net charts control, this component allow generate images in server-side in memory, this approach is the solution for my problem.

On the other hand this component it's integrated in .net framework 4.

Thanks for the comments.

k

Answer (score 0):

I Know it's very late to answer this, but I just finished sending flot charts in email. I am using MVC4 in  Asp.net.

I send the data to the view -> generate the graph with flot with javascript  -> converted the canvas to base64 -> send it back to the server through ajax .

I did this for automated reporting and everything is working fine  .